# ¿Cómo renombrar los datos (filas) de una columna en específico?

Tags: r, dataframe

buenos días
he intentado a través de diversos comando renombrar las filas de la columna año, ya que necesito que sea numérico y no de carácter.
he intentado con rownames, con rename -aunque nos dimos cuenta que realmente nosotros estamos renombrando los datos no la variables, por lo que eso no está bien-.

Entonces, lo que busco es que dentro de mi base de datos "matrícula", todos los valores de la columna año llamados MAT_2020, cambien solo a 2020 y todos los MAT_2019, cambien a 2019 y así hasta el 2015.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más simple, siempre que `MAT_` se repita siempre, es usar [`gsub()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep) para eliminar directamente ese patrón y quedarnos solo con la parte numérica de la columna:

```
df$año <- gsub('MAT_', '', df$año)
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @AlejandraLagos? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!